# Kendo Angular 2 Grid 0.12.0 Doesn't Compile in AOT

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I recently upgraded from 0.7.0 to 0.12.0 for the Kendo Grid for Angular 2 (@progress/kendo-angular-grid).  My app compiles fine when not in AOP, but as soon as I attempt to compile in AOT it fails.  I am using the Angular 2 CLI command "ng b --prod --aot".  The error follows below.

---

10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 activecan't resolve module ./field-accessor.pipe from C:/Paylocity/paylocity.reporting/src/paylocity.reporting.web/Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/shared.module.d.ts
Cannot read property 'FieldAccessorPipe' of undefined, resolving symbol SharedModule in C:/Paylocity/paylocity.reporting/src/paylocity.reporting.web/Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/shared.module.d.ts, resolving symbol SharedModule in C:/Paylocity/paylocity.reporting/src/paylocity.reporting.web/Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/shared.module.d.ts
Error: Cannot read property 'FieldAccessorPipe' of undefined, resolving symbol SharedModule in C:/Paylocity/paylocity.reporting/src/paylocity.reporting.web/Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/shared.module.d.ts, resolving symbol SharedModule in C:/Paylocity/paylocity.reporting/src/paylocity.reporting.web/Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/shared.module.d.ts
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\chuckj\src\angular\modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.ts:537:15)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\chuckj\src\angular\modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.ts:541:20)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\chuckj\src\angular\modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.ts:93:28)
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14261:46)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14646:45)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleSummary (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14615:33)
    at C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14673:57
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14660:51)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getUnloadedNgModuleMetadata (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14636:23)
    at addNgModule (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12944:43)
    at C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12957:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _createNgModules (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12956:28)
    at analyzeNgModules (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12700:16)
    at analyzeAndValidateNgModules (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12704:20)
    at OfflineCompiler.compileModules (C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12775:20)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\Users\chuckj\src\angular\modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.ts:71:26)
    at C:\Paylocity\paylocity.reporting\src\paylocity.reporting.web\Paylocity.Reporting.Web.Client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:210:73
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Answer (score 0):

You can try latest `@progress/kendo-angular-grid` version (currently ***0.12.1***). Our builds for AoT are running against *Angular 2.4.x* and all seems to be running smoothly.